# Compilation error when templating my class on coordinate type and using Boost Geometry library

Tags: c++, templates, boost, g++, boost-geometry

I'm writing a library code on top of Boost Geometry library. My class should be templated on the coordinate type (usually int/float/double etc.).
The code below (stripped down to bare minimum) doesn't compile and I get a compilation error that doesn't help me.

The code:

```
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point.hpp>

template <typename CoordType>
class MyClass {
public:
    typedef boost::geometry::model::point<CoordType, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian> MyPoint;
    CoordType getX(const MyClass<CoordType>::MyPoint &p) const { return p.get<0>(); }
};
```

The error:

```
test.cpp: In member function 'CoordType MyClass<CoordType>::getX(const MyClass<CoordType>::MyPoint&) const':
test.cpp:8:82: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
```

I'm compiling this code with: `g++ -I./boost_1_54_0 test.cpp -o test.o`. I used different versions of G++ 4.5.2/4.7.2/4.8.1, but I still get the same error.

What am I missing here?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not entirely relevant to solving your problem, but [boost docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/models/model_point.html) recommend using the free function `boost::geometry::get<0>(p);` instead of the member function.

Comment: @us2012 Thanks. This worked both for the test code and for the real code.

Comment: Well, since my idea worked, let me shamelessly post it as an answer ;) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the free function `boost::geometry::get<0>(p);` recommended [in the boost docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/models/model_point.html) circumvents this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the answer of us2012, using boost::geometry::get<0>() is recommended.

The actual problem was that the template keyword was missing, so this:

{ return p.**template** get<0>(); }

would have fixed the problem.